# How to use Typescript or an UMD module in a WebSite project(not SPA)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, asp.net-core, module

Typescript is a great language, but I haven't use it in my project, the reason is that my project is a traditional website with many page (asp.net core MVC), and all tutorial I can found is for SPA (anglerjs,vuejs ect.) and I use many jquery plugins in my project. and I'm confusing about javascript's module system.

and here is my question:

1. do I must using npm, and how do I configurate it to download package to the folder I wanted ?
2. how do I load jquery and it's plugin ?
3. what module loader should i use?
4. do I must use webpack ? and how to config (multiple output files are needed)
5. I already try to use typescript without module , and use `namespace` instead but a problem is that I can't define a repeated public function or variable (sometime I copy and paste code from one to another, and a few file structure similar but not the same (they expose the same variable but they don't in one page))

**I know there a lots of question there, but even if you only know one answer of above question, please share you answer to me! it will be really helpful**

Comment: This is a lot of questions and very broad. But TypeScript doesn’t require any modules or loaders, by default transpiles file for file and doesn’t care about SPA or anything. Anything you do with it is your choice and your requirements aren’t clear here.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I must useing TypeDefinition and that means I must using NPM, and using NPM  the problem is the location of  node_module is not I wanted (previously I use bower and I can config which folder to store packages ) , any suggestions ?